# How to run a NodeJS app from a subfolder of a WP site powered by Nginx, Varnish and php-fpm

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxypass

I've been trying to run a NodeJS application from a WP site's subfolder. The WP site is running on Nginx, Varnish and php-fpm.

From the error log file, I'm getting messages like this:

```
[error] 26790#0: *428 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: doufeelme.com, request: "GET /forum/user-591.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4567/forum/user-591.html", host: "doufeelme.com"
```

On the browser, I'm getting **502 Bad Gateway**.

Here's the NodeJS app's *config.json* file. Note: For **relative_path**, I have also tried */forum*, but got the same error message.

```
{
"base_url": "http://doufeelme.com",
"port": "4567",
"use_port": true,
"secret": "secret",
"bind_address": "0.0.0.0",
"database": "redis",
"redis": {
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "port": "6379",
    "password": "secret2",
    "database": "0"
},
"bcrypt_rounds": 12,
"upload_path": "/public/uploads",
"relative_path": ""
```

}

And here's my Nginx config:

```
##
server {

## Your website name goes here.
server_name doufeelme.com;

## Your only path reference.
root  /home../public_html/;
listen 8080;
## This should be in your http block and if it is, it's not needed here.
index index.html index.htm index.php;

include conf.d/drop;

    location / {
            # This is cool because no php is touched for static content
                    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_buffers 8 256k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;


    }

    location ~* \.(css|js|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
            expires 1d;
    }

## Settings for proxying NodeJS app.

    location ^~ /forum {

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4567;
    proxy_redirect off;

    # Socket.IO Support
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

}
```

}

For the proxy location, I've tried `location /forum` and `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4567/forum`, but still got the same error message.

I think I've run out of ways of messing with **location**, **proxy_pass** and **relative_path**.

Any clues?

Btw, the WP site runs just fine, even now.

TIA.